# On Mouse Touch in android

Tags: android

which function is used for keeping track of all user interactions in Android?

I have used the `onuserinteraction()` function, but that does not include touching the mouse.
It includes clicking the mouse or any key event.

So is there any function which keeps track of touching the mouse also?

Comment: What do you mean by "the mouse" ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links:

[View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

[Learn Android Tutorial 1.32 – Android’s OnTouchListener and MotionEvent](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3279/android-the-basics-32-androids-ontouchlistener-and-motionevent/)

I hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think android has a "mouse". U can only use onClick listeners.